# How To Display only First Word of H2 Heading With JavaScript or CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I Just wanted to know, is there any way though which we can display only First Word from h2 Heading.

For Example:

In the source code it should look like this

```
<h2> Stackoverflow is an Ideal Place</h2>
```

However, on live website it should look like this

```
Stackoverflow
```

Basically, we want to display the FIRST WORD from the whole heading. However, Search engine should read the complete title.

Comment: Maybe Changing the width? Changing the color? What have you tried?

Comment: Maybe explain why you can't just change the source code (which would be the obvious answer).

Comment: Well, I Justed Wanted to display the First Word from the H2 Heading. Is there anyway of doing that. @DanielA.White

Comment: @Enve Not a dupe. Those answers would require OP to include a bloated library.

Comment: Here look at a Example here http://www.soratemplates.com/. The post titles on this site contains more then 3 words but only the first word is displaying.

Comment: Uhhmmm no! Those are only 1 word.

Comment: @SyedFaizanAli I don't see your example...

Comment: @PeeHaa I don't think so check their Source code

<h3 class='post-title'>
<a href='http://www.soratemplates.com/2012/12/sunrise-blogger-template.html' title='Sunrise Blogger Template'>Sunrise Blogger Template</a>
</h3>

Comment: You are looking on the next page, not the page you linked to?

Comment: @PeeHaa I am Talking about the HomePage. Do check its source code. the post titles are with more then 1 Word.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ac = $("#ac").text().split(' '); 
    $("#ac").text(ac[0])
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do this with just CSS. You have pseudo-element selector for first letter, first line, but not first word.

You can set a width so that only the first word is visible (and use `overflow:hidden` of course), but that's not foolproof for all font families and sizes.

Finally you can do it with plain JavaScript or jQuery.

Plain JS:

```
var el = document.getElementById("ac");
el.innerHTML = el.innerHTML.split(/\s/)[0];
```

jQuery:

```
$("#ac").html(function(i, h) { return h.split(/\s/)[0];});
```

Answer (score 1):

This will do what you want it to...

```
<h2 id="ac">Stackoverflow is an Ideal Place</h2>​

$('#ac').html( function(i, h) {
    var words = h.split(/\s/);
    return ' <h2>' + words[0] + '</h2>';
});​
```